# How to find the minimum possible number of actions for unsorted stack using second stack?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, stack

Given sorted array with its unsorted version implemented as stack and an empty stack. The task is to find the minimum possible actions (swap 1st 2 elements, pop from one push to another one, shift, reverse shift) for those 2 stacks so the 1st stack becomes sorted. I really tried to find any algorithm, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: A stack does not normally include a shift operation. Push and pop are required, so is some type of compare operation. With two variables, a swap can be done using pop and push. I assume you are looking for the minimum number of types of operations, as opposed to minimizing the running time of the sorting algorithm.

Comment: It's been over a day. I suggest doing a web search for "two stack sort". You will find examples of pseudo code to base your answer on.  Almost all of these two stack sorts end up with the sorted data in the 2nd stack, but to remedy this, just sort in "descending" order, then pop / push all of the 2nd stack to the 1st stack to end up with the 1st stack sorted. This will no require any different "actions" than the sort itself requires.